# awk : syntax error

Tags: awk

Below is the code:

```
for i in "${x[@]}"
do
        z+=$(awk '$1 == '$i' {print $2}' $file)
done
echo "${z[@]}"
```

It is giving following error with desire output:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: $1 ==  {print $2}
awk: cmd. line:1:        ^ syntax error
```

I am guessing that when `$1` value is not matching with `$i` value it is showing this error.

Can someone tell me how this can be handle?

I tried with `-v`:

```
z+=$(awk -v '$1 == '$i' {print $2}' $file)
```

but it is giving fatal:

```
awk: fatal: `$1 ' is not a legal variable name
```

Comment: you're sure the `x` array doesn't have an empty value in it? (`x=("")`)

Comment: `x` array doesn't have an empty value in it.

Answer (score 1):

Pass $i to awk as a variable and so:

```
z+=$(awk -v vari="$i" '$1 == vari {print $2}' "$file")
```

Comment: It hanged, no output.